# PDFKit XMP data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdfkit

I need to store my own table of metadata within a pdf that is not visible if it is opened with a standard PDF viewer.  Is it possible to add/edit XMP data in a pdf with PDFKit or Quartz?